# Request CircuitLab Schematic Editor for Mechanics.SE

Tags: feature-request

EE.SE (electronics.stackexchange.com) has a WYSIWYG editor that allows stack users to create and edit schematics for posting. This should be requested for integration on Mechanics.SE. It would not take much for the SE devs to enable, and would allow electrical wiring questions to be more easily answered.

See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24309/led-lights-on-same-switch for an example of the schematic added.

Comment: There would be a lot of things I'd like to see on Mechanics.SE. This would be a good addition as well. I know there have been other suggestions given about add-ons for here, but heck if I can remember any of them except for the inline video display. Not that it would get used a lot, but it sure would come in handy.

Comment: I'd like to have that.  I would use it when it appropriate.